# Microsoft Access UPDATE command using C# OleDbConnection and Command NOT working

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, c#-4.0, oledb

I'm using Microsoft Access unfortunately because of higher forces and trying to update a record with no luck.

This is the code:

```
private void UpdateContact(Contact contact)
{
    using (OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(_connString))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [Contact] SET [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [MobileNumber] = @MobileNumber WHERE [Id] = @Id";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, db) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", contact.Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", contact.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", contact.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", contact.MobileNumber);

        db.Open();

        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine, no exception but no rowsAffected either. It always returns 0.
I have checked the values while debugging and its the correct that should persist.
The access file created with MS Access 2007 but its type is of 2002-2003.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
string query = "UPDATE [Contact] SET [FirstName] = ? [LastName] = ?, [MobileNumber] = ? WHERE [Id] = ?"
```

Add your parameters in the order of the statement, i.e. firstname...id

Comment: MS Access really sucks. Even it is not following the standard SQL rules. I am passing parameters to my query and mentioning parameters by name in that SQL query, however MS access is ignoring the parameter name and taking it in sequence of field appearing in query. Really such a weird behavior of such a good database back-end.

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need ? for the place holder and the parameters must be added in the order in which they occur: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx