# Query to update values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm trying to update my database i.e. a MS Access file, I want to update my table by taking the values from the textboxes but I'm not able to write a proper query.

Can anyone please help me to write a proper update query?

```
string strconn4 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|pay.accdb";

OleDbConnection sqlconn4 = new OleDbConnection(strconn4);
sqlconn4.Open();    
OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE fees SET fname=" + Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text) + ",lname=" + Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text) + ",amtpayd=" + Convert.ToString(textBox4.Text) + ",amtleft=" + Convert.ToString(textBox5.Text) + ",disc=" + Convert.ToString(textBox6.Text) + ",pdate=" + Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker3.Text) + ",rdate=" + Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Text) + ",WHERE memid=" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text), sqlconn4);
```

Comment: Please post the query you tried and the error it is raising. (And sufficient information about the underlying table so people can understand what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Also if you post SELECT query, that might give us more info.

Comment: hii i have updated my problem ... please help me out

Comment: @ParthKalra you need to provide what error you/exception you get - otherwise it is hard to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is a very serious security problem!

You should use parameterized queries instead.

Some links on how build such queries including references and samples:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx
- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589424/847363
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/accessdev/thread/33f3f6bc-03b2-4f64-84ca-cef65bbc0eee

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
   string sql=string.Format("UPDATE Table1 SET column1='{0}',column2='{1}' where id={2}",tbx1.text,tbx2.text,tbx3.text);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = strconn4;
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```