# Update statement doesn't update my data

Tags: c#, .net, database, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I would like to update/edit my user data in Employee table in access database.

When i complete the fields that i want to change (name , last name, etc.), it gives me **data updated** but when i refresh the table, the data hasn't changed - been updated.

**Changes i want to perform for example** - Change name from Luke to Taylor, etc.

Where have i gone wrong? Where is the mistake in the code and does my code for **adding users to database** somehow have influence my update code?

My code for adding users is almost the same as for the update, except for query, and it works fine.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "Update Employee set Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, UserName = @UserName, Password = @Password, E_mail = @E_mail, Address = @Address WHERE ID = @ID";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_mail", email.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);

            myConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User updated!");
            myConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Code for adding user data**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "Insert into Employee (ID, Name, LastName, UserName, Password, E_mail, Address)" + "values (@ID, @Name, @LastName, @UserName, @Password, @E_mail, @Address)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_mail", email.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);

            myConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User added!");
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the replies and help

---

I still have no solution for this. I've tried so many things but i just don't get the right answer.

**My current code**

```
 try
        {
            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("\\DATABASE PATH");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Employees SET Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, UserName = @UserName, Password = @Password, E_mail = @E_mail, Address = @Address WHERE ID = @";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_mail", eMail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);

            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User successfully added.");
            myConnection.Close();
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
```

Comment: can you post the code you use to add a user? Might help identify issues.

Comment: sure thing, i just edited my post

Comment: Are you creating your own IDs? Are you generating them manually? Or is the DB supposed to auto-generate them? It looks as if you're creating your own ID. Are you enforcing uniqueness?

Comment: I am creating them Manually. I have a textbox field where i enter ID. I don't really know how to generate them. And yes the user is suppose to have unique ID

Comment: The most likely explanation seems to be that when the Update button is clicked that the ID has changed. Just check carefully that the ID that ends up in your update code actually matches the ID of the row in the Database that was successfully added. Perhaps the answer below is correct but I don't really understand the way he has expressed it.

Comment: but how can it change when i type the same exact ID in textbox? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @DanielC, i dont wanna bother, but i still don't have the solution for this and i need it today =\. I just don't get it why does this not update my info.

Comment: the new code you posted does not agree with the original code. I'm not an expert in Access SQL but I also believe that both `Name` and `Password` need to be surrounded by square brackets in both SQL statements. Also I can't see how your Add code could work as there is no space between the INSERT portion and the VALUES portion. I have posted a possible answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your update code:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Employee SET [Name] = ?, LastName = ?, UserName = ?, [Password] = ?, [E_mail] = ?, Address = ? WHERE [ID] = ?";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_mail", email.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
```

The parameters must be in the order in which they appear in the `CommandText`. This answer was suggested by: [Microsoft Access UPDATE command using C# OleDbConnection and Command NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589348/microsoft-access-update-command-using-c-sharp-oledbconnection-and-command-not-wo)

The reasons for this is outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Answer (score 2):

Its because your ID in where condition.

You are also changing/updating your ID through:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
```

This new ID is not found by compiler in Database since you kept where ID=@ID condition in your query.

When you just updates name and other fields then query becomes:

```
Update Employee set Name = 'Name', LastName = 'LastName', UserName = 'UserName', Password = 'Password', E_mail = 'E_mail', Address = 'Address' WHERE ID = ''";
```

Your ID might remain blank in that case.

Comment: so that means i should delete the **command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.text); but keep the **WHERE** condition - like the one u wrote above?

Comment: not exactly like that, but u need to keep your userID.text permanant or the value that exists in database

Comment: and how do i achieve that?